# Unable to fetch list of files from back-end to front-end angular select options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, express

I am getting files from directory('.public/jsonfiles') in `server.js` file using `node.js`. But I am failing to get these list of files to show on my view page using `AngularJS` with my `Node.js` service.

Error:

I am getting `data.forEach` is not a function error(I can see total html content in the console instead of my list of files in my service file on return statement: `return $http.get('/public/jsonfiles');`

Otherwise if I give: `return $http.get('').then(function(data){ console.log(data)});` /giving `Main.get()` success is not a function and giving total of `html content on console`

Created [repository](https://github.com/mavarma/GetListofFiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your repo. On the request

```
 return $http.get('/public/jsonfiles');
```

node will return index.html which will then make MainCtrl error on **data.forEach** as data is not an array.

If you install [serve-index](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index) and use it to provide directory listing for **public** it should work.

```
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
app.use('/public',serveIndex('public'));
```

(server.js)

To load the file json add another method to the MainService to get the file.

```
    getFile: function (filename) {
        //no public in the path because node is removing when it serves static files
        return $http.get('/jsonfiles/' + filename);
    }
```

In MainCtrl you can the load the file contents when the selected file is changed.

```
  $scope.optionChanged = function () {
     Main.getFile( $scope.selectedjsoncontent )
         .success(function(result){
           $scope.textAreaData = result;
         });
```

}

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have installed serve-index and added above two lines of code in server.js, but I am getting same error, I hope that do I need to re-configure or need to add/ger properly anything in server.js ? Kindly let me know please and I have updated my repo: https://github.com/mavarma/GetListofFiles

Comment: @Dhana Can you try with **app.use('/public/jsonfiles',serveIndex('public/jsonfiles/'));**. That is working for me.

Comment: yes its working fine now, as per your statement, but it's giving the filenames, I mean I need their respective selected option data(I need to get json data instead of their filenames in my text area)

Comment: I need to display my selected option's json content in the textarea instead of showing the json file names.

Comment: @Dhana you will have to do another get request with the filename when the selected options changes to get the content and load the result into a property on the controller. You can then bind that property to the text area.

Comment: yes, I have written it in my controller: Main.get().success(function(data){
              data.forEach(function(obj){
               $scope.JSONFiles.push(obj);
              }), does this you want ? and  $scope.optionChanged = function(){
               $scope.textAreaData = $scope.selectedjson;
             }
         for selecting option in view page.

Comment: @Dhana I added the code to the answer, it's easier to read than in a comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it is working fine now, it helped me a lot and thank you for your support !!